# Infinite loop in django view

Tags: python, django

I've dwelled at this trying to figure out why I'm not returning the list of PrivateMessages. Sometimes a different pair of eyes can spot it right away so I'm posting this here hoping someone finds the error.

This is a function that gets 20 or less private messages and removes duplicate messages of the same user, that is only 1 message per user is going in the returned batch of pm's.

It also excludes users that are in the Silenced list. These have been working fine so I don't think it has to do with the Silenced bit.

After the call to remove_duplicate_users I get the last object's id to use it in the next query.

I rinse and repeat until I get 20 objects in the list ready to return or the query returns nothing.

```
def get_private_messages(request):
    ss = Silenced.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    last_pm_id = None
    n = 20
    bl = []
    while True:
        if last_pm_id:
            pmr = PrivateMessage.objects.filter(user=request.user,hidden=False,id__lt=last_pm_id).exclude(sender__in=[s.brat for s in ss]).order_by('-id')[:n]
        else:   
            pmr = PrivateMessage.objects.filter(user=request.user,hidden=False).exclude(sender__in=[s.brat for s in ss]).order_by('-id')[:n]
        l = list(pmr)
        bl = bl + l
        bl = remove_duplicate_senders(bl)
        n = 20 - len(bl)
        last_pm_id = bl[-1].id
        if len(bl) >= 20 or not pmr:
            break

    return HttpResponse(bl)
```

This is the function that removes duplicate user messages. It makes an exception for users named pin or note and if the pm.info1 matches welcome which only the first 10 pm's have.

```
def remove_duplicate_senders(pmr):
    l = []
    a = False
    for p in pmr:
        a = True
        if p.sender.username in ['pin','note'] or p.info1=='welcome':
            l.append(p)
            continue
        for px in l:
            if p.sender.username == px.sender.username:
                a = False
                break
        if a:
            l.append(p)
    return l
```

The user I'm testing with has over 60 pm's, yet I'm getting what appears to be an infinite loop when I try to retrieve the first 20 pm's. It works with other users but something in the way the pm's are ordered in the first user is causing the error.

Any insight in this is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Something weird about the loop in the second bit of code: you're adding things to `l` within the loop, then still within the loop you're looping through `l` itself. Is that right, or is in an indentation issue?

Comment: sorry I copied the first function wrong, I fixed it now.

Comment: Ugh such esoteric use of variable names. I see a few inconsistencies here off the bat, `return Httpresponse(pms)` (where is pms defined) and `sender__in=[s.breakt for s in ss]`, `sender__in=[s.brat for s in ss]` (believe should be the same). The function you've written doesn't have any infinite loop side effects, that much I can tell.

Comment: you are write about the s.breakt part I something went wrong with that it should be brat. And yes I removed the line were pms was declared, my bad, it was to avoid referencing another function that has nothing to do with the problem. I'll fix these.

Answer (score 0):

I think your break condition is invalid:

```
if len(bl) >= 20 or not pmr:
    # Stop if I have more than 20 messages? Shouldn't I continue filtering?
    break
```

Should be:

```
if n >= 0:
    # Stop only if I have 20 or less [n = 20 - len(bl)], continue otherwise
    break
```

I might have misunderstood something, but the last part of your while loop is the bit with the side effect. And please consider rewriting the code to make it more legible.

Comment: I want to get the first 20 messages or less if there are less. So n starts at 20 and is reduced to 20 - len(bl) that is 20 minus what messages are already in the big list. So I check if len(bl) is already 20 (or more if anything weird happened) or if the query is no longer returning anything (not pmr). Your suggestion of n>=0 would be true from the beggining. And the other way around n<=0 might not be true if there are less than 20 pm's

Comment: If you have 40 messages, your checking against `-20 >= 0` which is false and you don't break. If you have 16 messages, that's `4 >= 0` and you break. In either case, there might be something wrong in my reasoning with regards to how your code behaves, but it's definitely your break condition that's somehow inappropriate.

Comment: If I have only 16 messages, first some of them might get removed by remove_duplicate_users, then lets say im left with 7 messages. n will become 13, last_pm_id will become the id of the last message in the big list, let's say 234. At the condition it will fail both of them since bl is not >= 20 and pmr was not empty. Then at the next iteration it will search for pm's with an id lower than last_pm_id and it will return empty. bl will stay the same. it will fail bl>=20 but pmr will be false, then it should pass. I remove remove_duplicate_users the loop breaks just fine, so the problem is there..

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the case that too many pm's of the same user were in a row, so when it tried to  get the n number of private messages it never reached 20. I added a function to create a list of all the users in bl and excluded them in the query. Thanks for the replies.